# Create ModelChoiceField with annotation

Tags: django, forms, annotations

I need to make a selector with genders (male and female) with the respectives counts of each type.

For example, if I have 4 males and 8 females in my DB, I need a select tags with options

- "Select gender"
- "Male (4)"
- "Female (8)"

In my `Form` class I have

```
gender = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Gender.objects.all().annotate(counter=Count('user')),
        required=False,
        label="Gender"
    )
```

And I don't know how to render this select element. If I use `{{ form.gender }}` I can't even display the options. I get `Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type`. It could be an SQLite issue? I will use PostgreSQL as my DB anyway.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I need something like this, with almost 10 form fields and a variable number of options in each case

[image]

Comment: You should use `ChoiceField` rather than a `ModelChoiceField` because it render elements derived from queryset check here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Comment: @VaibhavMule `ChoiceField` doesn't support `queryset`, and I need to populate it with values from the DB. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. I tried this and it works fine. Modify it for your needs and it should work fine as well. I am just modifying the widget for gender field.

```
class testform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = names
        fields = ['name', 'gender']

    male = 'male'+str(names.objects.filter(gender='m').count())
    female = 'female'+str(names.objects.filter(gender='f').count())
    choices = ((male, male),(female,female))
    gender = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=choices))
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks!
Is there a way to make it in a more pythonic way? I have 10 fields like this, with option's number from 2 to 13 or more, so I will need something more general. I update my question with an image of what I would need.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `label_from_instance` method of `ModelChoiceField`:

```
class GenderModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name + ' ({})'.format(obj.counter)
```

And use this custom field in your form:

```
gender = GenderModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Gender.objects.all().annotate(counter=Count('user')),
    required=False,
    label="Gender"
)
```